# Replace value in column with multiple dictionary values

Tags: python, regex

I'm dealing with bird taxonomy and need to standardize common names.  The file to standardize consists of woodland guild species and consists of one column containing old common names.  The second file is a dictionary that lists old common names (keys) and new common names (values).  For example,

```
dict = {'BLUE GROUSE' : "DUSKY GROUSE", 'PLAIN TITMOUSE' : ["OAK TITMOUSE", 'JUNIPER TITMOUSE"], 'RUBY-THR. HUMMINGBIRD' : 'RUBY-THROATED HUMMINGBIRD'}
```

I want to replace the old names with the new names and have successfully accomplished this using the replace:

```
WoodlandGld["CommonName"].replace(StdCommonNames, inplace=True)
```

If a species has been split, as evidenced by the Plain Titmouse being split into the Oak and Juniper Titmouse, the value is a list and the *replace* replaces the first occurrence (which makes sense).

113                             PYGMY NUTHATCH

114                            TUFTED TITMOUSE

115                     BLACK-CRESTED TITMOUSE

116                               OAK TITMOUSE

117                     BLACK-CAPPED CHICKADEE

Is there a way to not only replace the first occurrence (Oak Titmouse) but also add the Juniper Titmouse as well when the key is encountered?  Is  *replace* the correct say to accomplish this?

Comment: It's rather unclear what sort of data structures you are using, and I doubt you will get an answer unless you specify better.  What exactly are `WoodlandGld[key]` and `StdCommonNames`?  Is one of those represented by your `dict` variable?  Try to provide a (small) example that people can reproduce and use to test on their own machines.  (Also, edit it into the question, rather than posting it as a reply to my comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f1 = ['BLUE GROUSE', 'PLAIN TITMOUSE', 'RUBY-THR. HUMMINGBIRD'] 
f2 = {'BLUE GROUSE' : 'DUSKY GROUSE', 
      'PLAIN TITMOUSE' : ['OAK TITMOUSE', 'JUNIPER TITMOUSE'], 
      'RUBY-THR. HUMMINGBIRD' : 'RUBY-THROATED HUMMINGBIRD'
     }

for k,v in zip(f2.keys(), f2.values()):    
    if type(v) == str:
        f1[f1.index(k)] = v
    else:
        f1[f1.index(k)] = v[0]
        f1.extend(v[1:])

f1.sort()   
print "Standardized list:", f1
```

Output:

```
Standardized list: ['DUSKY GROUSE', 'JUNIPER TITMOUSE', 'OAK TITMOUSE', 'RUBY-THROATED HUMMINGBIRD']
```

Note: the type of WoodlandGld is not clear i.e. dict or what, thus if you want a more precise help, please add more info.

Comment: WoodlandGld is a DataFrame (imported from an Excel workbook).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to replace name with values (one element or a list) in dict ,

```
name = ['BLUE GROUSE', 'PLAIN TITMOUSE', 'RUBY-THR. HUMMINGBIRD', 'OTHER KINDS'] 
dict = {'BLUE GROUSE' : 'DUSKY GROUSE',
      'PLAIN TITMOUSE' : ['OAK TITMOUSE', 'JUNIPER TITMOUSE'], 
      'RUBY-THR. HUMMINGBIRD' : 'RUBY-THROATED HUMMINGBIRD'
     }

for k in name:
    if k in dict:
        name[name.index(k)] = dict[k]

print ("Standardized list:\n", name)
```

Output

```
Standardized list: 
['DUSKY GROUSE', ['OAK TITMOUSE', 'JUNIPER TITMOUSE'], 'RUBY-THROATED HUMMINGBIRD', 'OTHER KINDS']
```